# Is it possible to restore a database with only database roles membership?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2016, restore

I have an existing database, that i want to restore from a backup by overriding the existing database.

at the moment I have

```
db_owner
db_backupoperator
```

roles

I thought that would be enough to restore the db. However when i try i get the error

```
User does not have permission to RESTORE database 'XY'
```

Is this achievable just with granting database roles (and without granting server role and fine tuning permissions?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions for detailed reference.

> If the database being restored does not exist, the user must have
>   CREATE DATABASE permissions to be able to execute RESTORE. If the
>   database exists, RESTORE permissions default to members of the
>   sysadmin and dbcreator fixed server roles and the owner (dbo) of the
>   database (for the FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT option, the database always
>   exists).
>
> RESTORE permissions are given to roles in which membership information
>   is always readily available to the server. Because fixed database role
>   membership can be checked only when the database is accessible and
>   undamaged, which is not always the case when RESTORE is executed,
>   members of the db_owner fixed database role do not have RESTORE
>   permissions.